# Bubbling up exceptions in coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In Kotlin coroutines, an `async` call will not throw until the value is retrieved. However, when I  launch a suspend function in an `async` block, the exception is not trapped as I would expect.

Here's the sample code:

```
fun start() {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        try {
            val def1 = async { doWork1() }
            val def2 = async { doWork2() }
            Log.d("test", "Result ${def1.await()}, ${def2.await()}")
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Log.e("test", "Error", ex)
        }
    }
}

private suspend fun doWork1(): Int {
    delay(1000L)
    throw Exception("work 1")
}

private suspend fun doWork2(): Int {
    delay(1000L)
    return 1
}
```

This crashes instead of trapping the exception in the `catch` block.

On the other hand, this works fine

```
fun start() {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        try {
            val value = doWork1()
            Log.d("test", "Result: $value")
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Log.e("test", "Error", ex)
        }
    }
}

private suspend fun doWork1(): Int {
    delay(1000L)
    throw Exception("work 1")
}
```

Why aren't exceptions trapped in the first example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second case is simple: you're only running 1 `job` with `GlobalScope.launch`, and `exception` is cleanly caught.

In first case however your `async` calls create jobs that are children of your `GlobalScope.launch`.

Exception is actually delayed until `await()` call, but it doesn't rethrow in that case. Instead `async` job propagates exception to its parent job (`launch`) which proceeds to cancel itself and all children jobs immediately. It forwards exception to its `ExceptionHandler` which by default is uncaught.

You should install exception handler on your parent job context - this allows clean handling of any exception within coroutine or its children:

```
GlobalScope.launch(CoroutineExceptionHandler { coroutineContext, throwable ->
        println("Error: $throwable")
}) {
    val def1 = async { doWork1() }
    val def2 = async { doWork2() }
    println("Result ${def1.await()} ${def2.await()}") 
}
```

Read in detail about coroutine exception handling in [Exception Handling](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html) docs.

Comment: Thanks, with the handler it does not crash. But why does it not work either if I do a try { launch { /* */ } } catch() { } ? Shouldn't the try/catch outside the parent coroutine catch the exception in this case/

Comment: I'll answer my own question - the exception happens on a different thread, so the try/catch block does not apply.